# Further customizing coloring using aliases, ls, and dircolors in .bashrc file

Tags: linux, colors, alias, ls

at the [ls man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ls) the `--colors` flag is of course explained, and at the bottom of the page there is reference made to the idea that further customization is made possible with [dir_colors](http://linux.die.net/man/5/dir_colors). I further found some helpful pages [written by others who have used dir_colors](http://linux-sxs.org/housekeeping/lscolors.html), but not enough to get me all the way to the answer I'm looking for.

What I would like to ask is this:

*What would I need to append to a .bashrc file to make files with a given extension appear in a given color?*

To take one example, how could I make all .sh files appear orange? Or all .tar.gz files appear red?

Answer (score -1):

There is no orange :-)

Here are bits and pieces from my ~/.dir_colors (inherited it many years ago)
which is loaded by eval `dircolors ~/.dir_colors` in .bashrc:

```
# Below are the color init strings for the basic file types. A color init
# string consists of one or more of the following numeric codes:
# Attribute codes: 
# 00=none 01=bold 04=underscore 05=blink 07=reverse 08=concealed
# Text color codes:
# 30=black 31=red 32=green 33=yellow 34=blue 35=magenta 36=cyan 37=white
# Background color codes:
# 40=black 41=red 42=green 43=yellow 44=blue 45=magenta 46=cyan 47=white
NORMAL 00       # global default, although everything should be something.
FILE 00         # normal file
DIR 01;34       # directory
LINK 01;36      # symbolic link
FIFO 40;33      # pipe
SOCK 00;35      # socket
BLK 40;33;01    # block device driver
CHR 40;33;01    # character device driver
ORPHAN 01;05;37;41  # orphaned syminks
MISSING 01;05;37;41 # ... and the files they point to
# This is for files with execute permission:
EXEC 01;32
```

and then some for .sh and .gz:

```
.sh  01;32 # executable in bold green
.csh 01;32
.tar 01;31 # archives or compressed (bright red)
.tgz 01;31
.arj 00;31
.taz 01;31
.lzh 00;31
.rar 01;31
.RAR 01;31
.zip 01;31
.ZIP 01;31
.z   01;31
.Z   01;31
.gz  01;31
.bz2 01;31
.bz  01;31
.tz  01;31
.jar 01;31
.rpm 01;31
.deb 01;31
.cpio 01;31
.iso 01;31
.ISO 01;31
```

as for orange, maybe yellow is good enough?

```
.sh  01;33 # shell in bold yellow
```

Comment: This answers the asker's example, but not their question. Explaining *why* the answer works would make it better: what does `01;33` mean?

Comment: /Why?/ is not a valid question. If you want to know /how/, then please read the comments in the code, in particular about attribute codes and textual color codes. Also the manual of /dircolor/ and don't forget the source of your OS kernel.